# Lightning Quick Actions Buffering Issue on Component

Tags: lightning, service-cloud-console, servicecloud, lightning-quickaction, field-dependencies

I am using Case Quick Actions layout on Case Page. Here as it can be seen, `Product` is `RENT`.

[image]

But when I click on inline Edit for any one of the fields in the layout, the value of `Product` becomes blank.

[image]

Since `Case Resolution` is dependent picklist on `Product`, the User is not able to select the `Resolution`. The API name and Label for the picklist on `Product` are the same. Strange, but how to resolve this? Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you check if the picklist option "RENT" is Active and if there are multiple record types its available for selected record type

Comment: yes its active and available for the record type